# Call PHP variable inside Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

my problem is when I try to use the value of a php variable within js.

This code works

```
var OmdbApi = 1fb4ed32;
```

But when I try to use the same value that I have stored in the variable, the code breaks

```
var OmdbApi = json_encode($mhflix_opc[\'omdb-api\']);
```

Full code:

```
function custom_admin_js() {
    echo '
    <script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(\'input[name=Checkbx]\').click(function() {
    var coc = jQuery(\'input[name=Checkbx2]\').get(0).value;      
    var OmdbApi = json_encode($mhflix_opc[\'omdb-api\']);
    jQuery.getJSON("https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=" + OmdbApi + "&i=" + coc, function(data) {
        var valDir = "";
        var valWri = "";
        var valAct = "";
        var valCou = "";
        jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
              jQuery(\'input[name=\' +key+ \']\').val(val); 
              if(key == "Director"){
                valDir+= " "+val+",";
              }
              if(key == "Writer"){
                valWri+= " "+val+",";
              }
              if(key == "Actors"){
                valAct+= " "+val+",";
              }
              if(key == "Country"){
                valCou+= " "+val+",";
              }
        });
        jQuery(\'#new-tag-director\').val(valDir);
        jQuery(\'#new-tag-escritor\').val(valWri);
        jQuery(\'#new-tag-actor\').val(valAct);
        jQuery(\'#new-tag-country\').val(valCou);
        alert(\'Se generó todo automáticamente.\');
    }); 
});
</script>';
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_admin_js');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function custom_admin_js() {
    //define the variable OmdbApi here, result must be a simple string
    $omdbApi = json_encode($mhflix_opc['omdb-api']);



    echo '<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(\'input[name=Checkbx]\').click(function() {
    var coc = jQuery(\'input[name=Checkbx2]\').get(0).value;';


    //Here we want to produce, depending on the value
    // var OmdbApi = 'ekrpweg' ;
    echo 'var OmdbApi = "' . $omdbApi . '" ;';

    echo 'the rest of the echo here';
}
```

Comment: What about if PHP `echo`s into a `script` block?

Comment: That's not a PHP variable, that's a JS variable.

Comment: Here is two version of the solution (with probable syntax error, do not remember). But the idea is here, do not expect PHP code to run on browser.

Comment: Uncaught reference error $mhflix_opc is not defined

But i tried var_dump($mhflix_opc['omdb-api']); and work, the problem is on js.

Comment: No it's not on JS, you just fix a php error... omg... happy your problem is solved

Comment: I edited to use `.` concatenation but long time not coding PHP... what does it produce now?

Comment: Thanks, its works. Little fix

echo 'var OmdbApi = "' . $omdbApi . '" ;';